# Overriding layoutAttributesForElementsInRect: of UICollectionView / PSTCollectionView causes visible cell to reload

Tags: iphone, ios, uicollectionview, sony, pstcollectionview

I want to mimic the features of gallery app provided in Sony Xperia in iPhone app. I gallary app, images are shown in grid grouped by date and the first photo of the section is twice in size than the others. On pinching out / in, all photos get zoom out / in.

[image]

I used PSTCollectionView as suggested by Lithu T.V and have created a custom layout. In that layout I have overridden `- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect`. Bellow is the code for same.

```
// called continuously as the rect changes
 - (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect {
 NSArray *attribs = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];

 NSMutableArray *arrmFrames=nil;
 for (int i=0;i<attribs.count;i++) {

     UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributesInitial=[attribs objectAtIndex:0];

     UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes=[attribs objectAtIndex:i];

     //Take initial frame from first cell
     if(i==0)
    fFirstCellsY = attributes.frame.origin.y;

     //while Y is constant, save the adjusted frames for next cells
     else if(attributes.frame.origin.y<fFirstCellsY+attributesInitial.frame.size.height)
     {
      if(arrmFrames==nil)
          arrmFrames=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

         attributes.frame=CGRectMake(attributes.frame.origin.x, attributesInitial.frame.origin.y, attributes.frame.size.width, attributes.frame.size.height);
         [arrmFrames addObject:NSStringFromCGRect(CGRectMake(attributes.frame.origin.x, attributes.frame.origin.y+attributes.frame.size.height+10, attributes.frame.size.width, attributes.frame.size.height))];
     }

     //Adjust the frame of other cells
     else
     {
         CGRect frame = attributes.frame;
         attributes.frame=CGRectFromString((NSString*)[arrmFrames objectAtIndex:0]);
         [arrmFrames removeObjectAtIndex:0];
         [arrmFrames addObject:NSStringFromCGRect(frame)];
     }

 }

 }

return attribs;
}
```

This works and the layout is looking like I wanted.
By this method more cells become visible than those by using default layout and my layout looks OK. but when I scroll down then some visible cells are getting reloaded. I guess the reason is the delegate method `- (PSUICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(PSUICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is getting called before `- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect` which is there in my custom layout. and so the cells which were not visible in default layout but visible in custom layout are reloaded late.

How can I overcome this?

Comment: Refer this tutorial.. http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12

Comment: @Kalpesh: Thanks. I can't use UICollectionView as the app is supposed to be able to work on iOS 5. Going through PSTCollectionView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [UICollectionView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html)
If app is supposed to support in less than 5.0 use [PSTCollectionView](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView)

[A nice startup](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I went through the tutorial & it really looks promising. Just one query, can images be zoomed in / out using pinch gesture using UICollectionView / PSTCollectionView?

Comment: I dont think they exist but can be included.It actually comes with methods for tap ,but pinch can be set up

Comment: Thank You.I mean, can it be done smoothly without blinking the collection view as while reloading it may blink.

Comment: Without blinking..I didnt tried it,But may be there is a way without doing the reloading

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your suggestion. I used PSTCollectionView with a custom layout which is working for me and the layout is also looking exactly like it was needed to. But that induced a problem when the cells get reloaded. Please see my edited question for details.

Comment: I have added related code to my question. Can you please help now?